# Why do a lot of methods of the TableViewController just have the name tableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm currently learning Swift and just implemented my first table.
To fill that table with dynamic data it's necessary to implement a class extending from TableViewController.

Now I'm wondering why some of the configuration methods just have the name tableView, for example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
```

Why didn't Apple give them names like:

```
override func getNumberOfRowsInSection(tableView: UITableView, section: Int) -> Int
override func getCellForRowAtIndexPath(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
override func canEditRowAtIndexPath(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
```

I'm sure there is a valid reason for that.

Comment: `UITableViewController` is written in Objective-C. There are historic reasons for this naming convention, but in general in Objective-C your talk about method signature rather than function names.

Comment: ... it's also a huge benefit for code completion ;-)

Comment: Beowulf, you should post your comment as an answer ("It is because of Objective-C method naming conventions"). That way the OP can accept it.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Well I agree with @beyowulf answer which is technically correct.

Objective-C is known for being a choppy/rough language to write with. Using `TableView` enables users to quickly search up every method related to the `UITableViewController` instead of typing up the `function` name to dig through an array of functions to find the one specifically for `UITableViewController`.

For example if you were to just type `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you would find the function  for `UICollectionViewController` and  `UITableViewController`. But if you typed `tableView` first you would only find the functions for `UITableViewController`.

Its just easier that way and hence why they built it like that.

Hope that clears it up.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer is wrong.

As these methods are delegate/datasource methods, they can be attached to multiple tableviews. So if your view has two tableviews, both of them can have the same method as their datasource. Because of this, a reference to which tableview that called the method is necessary, so you can do stuff like:

```
if tableView == myCoolYellowTableView { do stuff } 
else if tableView == myShittyBlueTable { do some other stuff }
```